# HTTP Headers to use to specify CSV delimiter and options

Tags: rest, csv, http-headers, content-type

I would like my REST service to accept CSV files in addition to JSON and XML.

I would accept an HTTP PUT request such as:

```
PUT /myservice/user
Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8

"tomas";"1980-01-01"
"george";"1981-02-02"
```

I would like to be able to accept different delimiters and other format options for my CSV file. Preferably without using the querystring, which doesn't seem to be the proper tool for that. I understand I could just invent my own headers such as:

```
PUT /myservice/user
Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8
CSV-Delimiter: ,
CSV-Options: merge-duplicates, no-header-row
```

Or maybe I could invent my own parameters to Content-Type if that is allowed (after all it is a part of the content-type just like the charset used):

```
PUT /myservice/user
Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8; delimiter=,; options=no-header-row
```

What would be the proper way to handle this? Are there any HTTP-headers conventionally used for this?

Comment: it could be argued that by not using a comma, you are not a CSV. A possible option is for the first line of the data to define what the delimiter should be. Or possibly wrap it in JSON `{"deliminater":";","data":"..."}`

Answer (score 2):

For "no-header-row" a parameter [already exists](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180#section-3): [header="present"|"absent"].

As for adding new parameters to the content-type header:

> New parameters SHOULD NOT be defined as a way to introduce new
> functionality in types registered in the standards tree, although new
> parameters MAY be added to convey additional information that does
> not otherwise change existing functionality.  An example of this
> would be a "revision" parameter to indicate a revision level of an
> external specification such as JPEG.  Similar behavior is encouraged
> for media types registered in the vendor or personal trees but is not
> required.